# Bad array subscript(UNIX)

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, dos2unix

hi guys i know this question has been asked several time out there.But i have tried a lot and i am not able to get what is the issue .Below is my code -:

```
#!/bin/bash



  #GLOBAL VARIABLE
  name=()
  browserTime=0
  browserScriptLocation=/global/z1/siebel/sweapp/public/enu
  value=0
  browserintegerDate=0

  browserscript_CreationTime(){
  # SET PATH
  cd $browserScriptLocation
  #LOOP INSIDE THE FILES PRESENT ON PARTICULAR PATH
  for entry in $(ls -t | grep  "srf*")
  do
  #APPEND SEARCHED FILE IN ARRAY AT INDEX 0
  name[value]="$entry"
  #INCREASE INDEX COUNT
  value+=1
  done
  name=${name[0]}
  echo "$name"
  #GET BROWSER SCRIPT TIME
  browserTime=$(ls -E "$name" | cut -c 52-60)
  echo "$browserTime"
  browserDate=$(ls -E "$name" | cut -c 41-51)
  echo "$browserDate"
  year=$(echo "$browserDate" | cut -c 1-5)
  month=$(echo "$browserDate" | cut -c 7-8)
  date=$(echo "$browserDate" | cut -c 10-11)
  browserintegerDate="$year$month$date"
  browserintegerDate+=$(echo $timeConversion)
   echo "$browserintegerDate"
}

#invoke your function
browserscript_CreationTim
```

**I am getting this error**-: `name[value]: bad array subscript`.The same code i have tested on other **UNIX BOX**. Both having same **OSversion (SunOS 5.10)** and it works fine over there.But it is not working on another one.I am not getting why is this happening?? Can anyone help??

Comment: And what is `value`? Don't you mean `$value`?

Comment: i tried that as well but still same error..:(

Comment: Two other possible problems: `value+=1` will not increase `value` by one. Considering that `value` is initialized with `0` the result will be `01` first time around in the loop. Second, `name=${name[0]}`? Are you sure you want to use the same name for both variables?

Comment: okk that error is not coming now but why my array is printing last index value instead of giving value at index 0????? The first time loop execute i store the file name in array which is at the top at index 0.But it is printing out last indx file can yoyu tell why??

Comment: how can i increment index count if not valid with value+=1??

Comment: How about `let value++`? Read more about [arithmetic evaluation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#ARITHMETIC_EVALUATION) in [the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).